# Lombok: Singular Builder and a default value

Tags: java, default-value, builder, lombok

Lombok version is 1.18.0.

I have `@Builder` set on class level.

When I try to set a default value for a list variable:

```
@Builder.Default
@Singular
private List<Class<? extends Exception>> retryTriggers = Lists.newArrayList(Exception.class);
```

I got an error:

```
Error:(46, 5) java: @Builder.Default and @Singular cannot be mixed.
```

Besides writing the builder myself, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest replacing the generated `builder()` method with the following one:

```
@Builder
class ExceptionHandler {
    @Singular
    private final List<Class<? extends Exception>> retryTriggers;

    public static ExceptionHandlerBuilder builder() {
        return new ExceptionHandlerBuilder().retryTrigger(Exception.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong for a scenario where you want the default value only if no other value has been set, this solution always adds the Exception.class to the final retryTriggers.

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz You're right - it doesn't work in such case (my answer does what the code from the question would most likely do, if it compiled).